# Script - Add a row beneath, based on conditional criteria

Tags: google-apps-script

Dear Oracles of the script,

I have been trying to get some script to automatically add a row beneath the one I have inputted on, but only if the Balance is anything BUT zero. If it's zero, I don't want another row adding.

I've tried a few scripts and looked around the site, and tried them with triggers with on edit, but they just seem to add a row, despite me trying to state a condition for them to trigger.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 12) { // 12 = column of input that triggers it

    var columnXRange = 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 13, 
 eventRange.getNumRows(), 12); /// column number it affects

    var values = columnXRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (!values[i][0]) {  // If cell isn't empty
       values[i][0] = '0';
      }
    }
        columnXRange.setValues(values);
       }
    }
    function Clear(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AGL');
    sheet.getRange('N4:N').clearContent();
    }

      function AddRow() {
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     if (sheet.getName() == "AGL") {
       var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
       if (activeCell.getColumn() == 13) {
      var Balance = sheet.getRange('N:N');
      if (Balance != '0'); {
      sheet.insertRowAfter(activeCell.getRow());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In column N, I have an array formula working out the balance of stock in, against stock out.

In column M, I have a script running that will add a 0 when something is put into column L. I also have a script that erases the output of the array formula, so they don't get tangled up with each other.

I would like, when editing a row, when I place a figure in column L or M, and if the balance in Column N is greater than 0, I would like a new row adding underneath. (If you can get it to add the values from A & B, that'd be a bonus, but not fussy.) If the balance is 0, I don't want a row adding.

Currently, I have mixed results with it just adding a row every time I edit column N.

Comment: Can you post an example of the sheet you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Requirement:

Add a row when columns L or M are edited and the value in column N is greater than 0 (& if possible, add values from columns A & B to the new row).

---

#### Solution:

This is pretty much all you need for your script. I've added comments to explain what each part is doing so it should be pretty easy to follow.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //define edited sheet, row number and column number
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  //get value of column N for edited row
  var val = sh.getRange(row, 14).getValue(); 

  //if columns L or M are edited and column N is greater than 0
  if ((col === 12 || col === 13) === true && val > 0) {

    //insert row below edited row
    sh.insertRowAfter(row); 

    //get values of columns A and B of edited row
    var vals = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues(); 

    //set values in columns A and B
    sh.getRange(row+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(vals);
  }
}
```

---

#### Notes:

I haven't included any of your other functions, only adding a row, you can incorporate these in this function if you desire.

You won't be able to run this script manually at all (it'll fail on the first line), it'll just run automatically when the sheet is edited.

---

#### References:

1. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
2. [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This works great! :) I did notice however that if a value is in L & M, and I amend any other columns after, it creates another row, but I can live with that! :)

Comment: My fault, I've amended the `if` statement now.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks! but for some reason, that amended one isn't working for me now. I think your first one is brilliant. :)

Comment: Hi Ross, I've made a few changes now to my sheet, and I wondered...is it possible to target specific columns, and miss some out when copying values to the next row?

Comment: Yeah it's totally possible - you can just build your own array of values and set it with `setValues()`.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks. I tried amending the script with code I had from a similar script (not mine, a friends) which used an array and meaningful headers, but I've had no luck..will the below work if I keep at it?                            // var MEANINGFUL_HEADERS = ['GRN','MASTER PO#'];

var meaningfulValuesExtractor_ = function(headers) {
  var hIndex = headers.reduce(function(p, c, i) {
    if (~MEANINGFUL_HEADERS.indexOf(c)) p.push(i);
    return p;
  }, []);
  return function(row) {
    return row.map(function(v, i) {
      return ~hIndex.indexOf(i) ? v : '';
    });
  };
};

Comment: Honestly you're probably better off asking a new question and putting the code and your new expected output there, it's pretty hard to tell what that code is doing with it all on the same line.